# Xlookup or vlookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

Hoping someone can help me out with some excel magic -

I have two sheets.
Sheet 1 has a list of names in column D
Sheet 2 has a list of names in column B and corresponding ID's in column A

I need to map the names in Sheet 1 column D with the ones in Sheet 2 column B and populate column E in sheet one with the right ID.

Comment: You need INDEX(MATCH()) - try asking Google for "[**vlookup vs index match**](https://www.google.com/search?q=vlookup+vs+index+match)"

Comment: looks like xlookup will do too ?

Comment: yes, xlookup should work, the only thing for you to be careful about is if you have duplicate names (but this would also be true of index/match)

Comment: If you have duplicate values and you want to return the last match XLOOKUP can do that for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions provided in the comments are correct, but I want to pull them together and explain when and how you would use each.

As you may have realized, VLOOKUP() won't work for this because you want to retrieve a value to the left of your lookup range.  There are two best-known ways to solve this.

- XLOOKUP, if you have O365 or Excel 2021 is a vastly improved and more versatile version of the old VLOOKUP;  If not, INDEX(MATCH()) is the way to go.

**If you do *not* have access to Excel 2021 or O365**

- Use INDEX(MATCH()).  In your case that would look something like this in cell E2 of sheet1 and copy it down:

`=INDEX( sheet2!A$2:A$100, MATCH( D2, sheet1!B$2:B$100 ) )`

**If you *do* have Excel 2021 or O365**

Then definitely use the XLOOKUP function in sheet 1, cell E2:

`=XLOOKUP( D2, sheet2!B$2:B$100, sheet2!A$2:A$100, "No ID")`

**In both cases:**

- Be mindful of the `$` to lock the lookup ranges, since you will most likely be copying this down the column rather than using an array formula.
- Both the examples assume that the values in sheet2 are rows 2 through 100.